# Concat two columns containing datepart

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to concact two result columns in one.
My query is:

```
 SELECT Datepart(Year, Date) As Annee, Datepart(Quarter, Date) AS Trimestre,
 Sum(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) A,
 Sum(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) B
 FROM myTable
 WHERE Date between '20150401' and '20160930'
 GROUP BY Datepart(Year, Date), DATEPART(Quarter, Date) 
 ORDER BY 1,2
```

I would like to get as result the first column like following:

```
|  Period  | A | B |
  2015 - 2
  2015 - 3
  2015 - 4
    ...
```

I tried to use "Select Concat(Datepart(Year, Date), Datepart(Quarter, Date)" and some other things that didn't work. Is what I want to do even possible?

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?. Which Version of `SQL SERVER` you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ue `datename()`:

```
SELECT datename(Year, Date) + ' - ' + datename(Quarter, Date) as Trimestre,
       Sum(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as A,
       Sum(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as B
FROM myTable
WHERE Date between '20150401' and '20160930'
GROUP BY datename(Year, Date) + ' - ' + datename(Quarter, Date) 
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

This returns a string, so you don't have to worry about conversion.

Answer (score 3):

Datepart returns a numeric. Convert it to string before concatenation.

```
select convert(varchar(4),datepart(year, getdate())) + ' - ' + convert(varchar(2),datepart(month, getdate()))
```

Comment: Or you could use a function that returns a string, like [DATENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms174395.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  But I prefer @NagarajRaveendran's soultion.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), 
    Datepart(Year,Date)), ' - ', 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(1), 
    Datepart(Quarter, Date))), ...
```